Unable to override left and right padding on MUI toolbar other than with !important
I have this Toolbar component from MUI 5.15.15 using Nextjs 14
It has default right and left paddings of 24px that I cannot override using any of the documented methods I've found on MUI's docs.

What I've tried:
1 - Overriding root styles in the theme object
components: {
  MuiToolbar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          paddingRight: '0',
          paddingLeft: '0',
        },
      },
    },
}

This doesn't work unless I add !important
2 - Using styled
const StyledToolbar = styled(Toolbar)<ToolbarProps>(() => ({
  padding: '40px 114px',
}))

Again, this only works when I add !important.
3 - Same thing when using the sx attribute
If I have to add the !important flag then what's the point of those solutions? I must be missing something but cannot figure out what.

What is the selector which adds this padding?

This is the selector @media (min-width: 600px) .mui-1igyjpu-MuiToolbar-root

The problem has to do with CSS specificity and order of the styles generated by MUI, the styles added to the component directly via the SX props or in the theme add the rules to the root element, and if we inspect the dev tools, after using the SX props for example you'll notice that the order of media queries classes overwrite the styles that we added:

<Toolbar sx={{ paddingRight: 0, paddingLeft: 0 }}>
  ...
</Tollbar>

So to solve this problem, we need to either increase the specificity or change the order of the styles generated by MUI.
For the second option, I noticed that when adding a media query class to the CSS, it will be injected beneath other media queries, so we can add the following class and it will work because they have the same specificity and the last one will win:
<Toolbar
  sx={{
    "@media (min-width: 0px)": { paddingRight: 0, paddingLeft: 0 },
  }}
>
...


A better approach is to increase the specificity of class that we use, if we use the AppBar used in the documentation, we can select the child from it and it will have a higher specificity as the following:
  <AppBar position="static" sx={{ "& .MuiToolbar-root": { padding: 0 } }}>
    <Toolbar sx={{ padding: 0 }}>
      ...

This will add the class of the parent + the class of the child, so it will overwrite any media queries styles because of its higher specificity.


There is a setting called disableGutters which worked for me
<Toolbar disableGutters>
    ...
</Toolbar>


masterful, thank you!
